# Who was Jafar al Kazzab? (Against Jafar al Sadiq(a.s.))

Tags: history, title

Someday, I was reading in a site…, I saw the name Jafar al Kazab.
Its name was written against the name of Imam Jafar al Sadiq(a.s.).

1. I was wondering who he was?
2. Why his title was Kazzab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He was Jafar bin Ali, the son of Ali al-Hadi, the 10th imam. He was called "al-Kathhab" or "the Liar" because he denied the existence of Muhammad al-Mahdi and wanted to takeover the imamate for himself.